# Why is one of the two strings below considered as a JSON array and the other one as a string? Python

Tags: python, json, pandas, string, dataframe

I am trying to make a PUT request and the API endpoint requires the payload to be structured as below:

```
payload_test = "[{\"id\": 1, \"channel_id\": 1, \"entity_type\": \"product\", \"entity_id\": 123, \"file_name\": \"custom-product-1.html\"}]"
```

I have imported values from a CSV file to create a similar string response using pandas and some string manipulation. This is my output when I print my string:

```
my_string = "[{\"id\": 1, \"channel_id\": 1, \"entity_type\": \"product\", \"entity_id\": 123, \"file_name\": \"product-custom-options.html\"}]"
```

I have created `my_string` to be identical to the original payload request but when I pass my_string I receive the following error: **The request payload has to be a JSON array for the endpoint**

The api call is succesful when I pass `payload_test` variable instead

This is how I created the `my_string` string:

The values for the id, channel_id etc are obtained from a dataframe (which is orgianally a csv file).

| id | channel_id | entity_type | entity_id | file_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | product | 123 | custom-product-1.html |
| 2 | 2 | product | 234 | custom-product-1.html |

```
df = pd.read_csv('xyz.csv')

for trial in df[['id', 'channel_id', 'entity_type', 'entity_id', 'file_name']].agg(pd.Series.to_json, axis='columns'):

    string1 = json.dumps(trial)

    my_string = string1[:1] + '[' + string1[1:-1] + ']"' #adding [ and ]" to the beginning and end

    my_string = my_string.replace(':', ': ')   #adding spaces after :

    my_string = my_string.replace(',', ', ')   #adding spaces after ,

    update_template(my_string, headers)
```

When I print the type for both the strings, it is: `<class 'str'>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `pd.Series.to_json` returns a string, not a JSON-like object (would have been a dict in this case). From the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_json.html):

> pandas.Series.to_json
> Convert the object to a JSON string.

Calling `json.dumps` on a string enclose it in a pair of double quotes and mess up everything after. Try this instead:

```py
for trial in df[['id', 'channel_id', 'entity_type', 'entity_id', 'file_name']].agg(pd.Series.to_json, axis='columns'):
    my_string = f'[{trial}]'.replace(':', ': ').replace(',', ', ')
```

The two `replace`s are not necessary and may even interfere with the fields' content.

Comment: This worked. Could you explain what f'[{trial}]' does? Thanks

Comment: It's string interpolation. A better example would be instead of writing `greeting = 'Hello ' + name +'. Welcome to the year ' + str(year)`, you can write `greeting = f'Hello {name}. Welcome to the year {year}'`. Read up on f-strings.